# Linear Regression using TF Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, linear-regression

I am new to TensorFlow and Deep Learning and have been trying to implement a basic linear regression model. I am using the `california_housing_train.csv` available in the sample_data folder in Colab, and using  3 features (`housing_median_age`, `total_bedrooms`, `population`) to predict `median_house_value`. But I am ending up with a terrible model no matter what.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

df = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_train.csv')
X = df[['housing_median_age', 'total_bedrooms', 'population']]
y = df['median_house_value']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

# Normalizing Layer
train = np.array(X_train)
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(input_shape=[3,], axis=None)
normalizer.adapt(train)

# Creating Model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([normalizer,
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])

model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.3),
              loss="mean_absolute_error")
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10, 

validation_split=0.3)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# R2 Score (Aim to get a better r2 score, but keep getting -ve)
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(r2)
```

Training for 10 epochs:

```
Epoch 1/10
595/595 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 96617.8047 - val_loss: 89414.4844
Epoch 2/10
595/595 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 92717.9062 - val_loss: 95228.3125
Epoch 3/10
595/595 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 90894.2812 - val_loss: 87268.4453
Epoch 4/10
595/595 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 91260.7578 - val_loss: 89836.5312
Epoch 5/10
595/595 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 89796.4375 - val_loss: 87359.7188
Epoch 6/10
595/595 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 89364.0000 - val_loss: 87501.6641
Epoch 7/10
595/595 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 89179.9922 - val_loss: 89818.0156
Epoch 8/10
595/595 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 88969.0312 - val_loss: 98786.2031
Epoch 9/10
595/595 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 89250.4531 - val_loss: 86751.1172
Epoch 10/10
595/595 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 88562.3828 - val_loss: 87661.0703
107/107 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step
-0.04170347420320697
```

I increased the no.of epochs, but it did not make much difference. I tried different learning rates, loss functions, optimizers, and no.of layers, but nothing is making much of a difference.

Hoping for some directions on what to change and how to proceed. I would also like some tips on how to go about selecting these factors when building a model in general.

Comment: Here is a [tuning playbook](https://github.com/google-research/tuning_playbook) that might help you

Answer (score 0):

Only 3 features is not enough to predict the target variable. So, try using more features.

Also, a fully-connected neural network doesn't seem to be working. I tried XGBoost and it's working just fine.

In the example below, I'm using `XGBRegressor` and 4 features to achieve an R2 score of 0.642:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

df = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_train.csv')
X = df[['housing_median_age', 'total_bedrooms', 'population', 'median_income']]
y = df['median_house_value']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)


model = XGBRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(r2)
```